# How to extract one object in a multi-objects TopoJSON file to another separate TopoJSON file

Tags: json, dictionary, geo, topojson

Using:

```
topojson -o foobar.json -- foo.json bar.json
```

We can combine two `foo.json` and `bar.json` into `foobar.json`:

The above foobar.json looks something like this:

```
{
    "type": "Topology",
    "transform": …,
    "objects": {
        "foo": …,
        "bar": …
    },
    "arcs": …
}
```

Now, I have `foobar.json`, how can I extract `foo.json` from it?

NOTE:

I do not need to convert TopoJSON to GeoJSON. foobar.json can also be in the TopoJSON format. I just need to reduce the size of foobar.json and remove the 'bar' object and its corresponding arcs.

For example, the us.json here https://gist.github.com/mbostock/4090846#file-us-json, includes three objects: 'counties', 'states', and 'landlines'. And I only need states.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract `foo` from you TopoJSON object using the clientside library. Assuming here `foobar` holds your TopoJSON object:

```
var foo = topojson.feature(foobar, foobar.objects.foo),
    bar = topojson.feature(foobar, foobar.objects.bar);
```

Now variable `foo` and `bar` hold the Feature/FeatureCollection originally stored in their respective files. See the reference for the clientside API on the wiki of the repository:

https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/wiki/API-Reference#client-api

Edit after comments and question edit:

Another option might be is to manually remove the other properties from the `objects` object in your TopoJSON. How to do this depends on the languages you have at your disposal. In php for example:

```
$string = file_get_contents('foobar.json');
$topojson = json_decode($string);
unset($topojson->objects->bar);
$string = json_encode($topojson);
file_put_contents('foo.json', $string);
```

Problem is that afterwards there will be unused arcs in the TopoJSON but to my understanding you can prune those using the `prune` method of the commandline interface:

> Removes any unused arcs from the specified topology.

https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/wiki/API-Reference#prune

Comment: Thanks for this client side solution. But I really need to solve this using the command line interface. I need to shrink the json file and remove those unnecessary parts.

Comment: Since you're working on commandline isn't it an option to simply not bundle the jsons in the first place and create separate topojson objects? If not you could always use the clientside library on the serverside using Node. I frankly think it's not possible using the serverside command line interface. It's purpose is to encode GeoJSON to TopoJSON. It can't decode TopoJSON to GeoJSON. That's what the clientside library is for.

Comment: The problem is I do not have foo.json and bar.json in the first place. I only have foobar.json. For example, the us.json here https://gist.github.com/mbostock/4090846#file-us-json, which includes 'counties', 'states', and 'landlines' three objects. And I only need states.

Comment: I've added another option to my answer but am unsure to it's validity since i am unable to test it atm. Hope it helps, good luck